# Is there a way to import an entire audio file from a database into HTML and use said file as the source of an <audio> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sql, flask

I've been writing a program with generate melodies, and I want to make a forum template where everybody can see what others have done. In order to do that, I was intending to save the files as a wave buffer with SQL and then paste them in the  tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html language="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            forum
        </title>

    </head>
    <body>
        {% for solos in solos %}
            <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ solos.date }} - {{ solos.title }}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <audio controls preload="auto">
                        <source = '{{ solos.song }}'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

However, it's it's not playing any sound, and I suspect that's because the source tag isn't valid.
What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to save your audio files in a separate folder in your server, not in your database. In your database you can have a table to save the info of each file (id, name, format, author, path, etc.). Then, whenever you want to retreive a particular audio file, you go to the db to get the path, and return the file in that path. This way you can use the audio tag in HTML without worrying about the file format.

Saving blob files in a db is generally inefficient, specially when your idea is to serve them to a client.

Comment: You are most likely right, I should do that. I wanted to put it directly in the database because I'm doing a project with a strict size limit, but I figure the file would weigh about as much inside the db.

Comment: You are right. You have very few advantages by saving the file in the db, as you can check here -> https://habiletechnologies.com/blog/better-saving-files-database-file-system/
I don't think the benefits are worth it, tbh. In my experience I've never come across a situation where files get saved in the db.